# Is there a hook for Executor Startup in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, callback, executor

So, basically I want multiple tasks running on the same node/executor to read data from a shared memory. For that I need some initialization function that would load the data into the memory before the tasks are started. If Spark provides a hook for an Executor startup, I could put this initialization code in that callback function, with the tasks only running after this startup is completed.

So, my question is, does Spark provides such hooks? If not, with which other method, I can achieve the same?

Answer (score 2):

Spark's solution for "shared data" is using **broadcast** - where you load the data once in the *driver* application and Spark serializes it and sends to each of the executors (once). If a task uses that data, Spark will make sure it's there before the task is executed. For example:

```
object MySparkTransformation {

  def transform(rdd: RDD[String], sc: SparkContext): RDD[Int] = {
    val mySharedData: Map[String, Int] = loadDataOnce()
    val broadcast = sc.broadcast(mySharedData)
    rdd.map(r => broadcast.value(r))
  }
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to avoid reading the data into driver memory and sending it over to the executors, you can use `lazy` values in a Scala `object` to create a value that gets populated **once per JVM**, which in Spark's case is once per executor. For example:

```
// must be an object, otherwise will be serialized and sent from driver
object MySharedResource {
  lazy val mySharedData: Map[String, Int] = loadDataOnce()
}

// If you use mySharedData in a Spark transformation, 
// the "local" copy in each executor will be used:
object MySparkTransformation {
  def transform(rdd: RDD[String]): RDD[Int] = {
    // Spark won't include MySharedResource.mySharedData in the 
    // serialized task sent from driver, since it's "static"
    rdd.map(r => MySharedResource.mySharedData(r))
  }
}
```

In practice, you'll have one copy of `mySharedData` in each executor.

Comment: Yes, I'm already aware of the broadcast function, but the reason I don't want to use it is because my tasks would be running an executable file, the code compiled through a C program. I want to load that data straight from an HDFS file, and put the data into a shared memory, so that those tasks can use it. Of course I would also have to modify the C code for that a little bit. The lazy val thing looks more appropriate for this purpose. So, I will check out that.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to run multiple instances of the app to be able to run multiple tasks (i.e. one app instance, one Spark task). The same SparkSession object can be used by multiple threads to submit Spark tasks in parallel.

So it may work like this:

- The application starts up and runs an initialization function to load shared data in memory. Say, into a SharedData class object.
- SparkSession is created
- A thread pool is created, each thread has access to (SparkSession, SharedData) objects
- Each thread creates Spark task using shared SparkSession and SharedData
  objects.
- Depending on your use case, the application then does one of the following:

  - waits for all tasks to complete and then closes Spark Session
  - waits in a loop for new requests to arrive and creates new Spark tasks as necessary using threads from the thread pool.

SparkContext (sparkSession.sparkContext) is useful when you want to do per-thread things like assigning a task description using `setJobDescription` or assigning a group to the task using `setJobGroup` so related tasks can be cancelled simultaneously using `cancelJobGroup`. You can also tweak priority for the tasks that use the same pool, see https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/job-scheduling.html#scheduling-within-an-application for details.

Comment: this is all true, but it's impossible if "SharedData" isn't serializable, and not too efficient if it is serializable but large. Using "SharedData" created on driver application directly in Spark transformations would mean it would get serialized and sent to executor **per task**.

Comment: @TzachZohar good point about SharedData sent to executor per task. Yes, the usage of a broadcast variable for SharedData would help to avoid this. The serialization requirement though applies to both variables in closure and broadcast variables as well, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, serializability requirement holds for broadcast too; But not for the "static" initialization option I've also mentioned, which (if I'm reading it right) is what the OP is aiming for.